# ASP.NET redirect to a page when a specific error occurs on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Sorry if this is a duplicate question. However, I've tried looking for the answer and can't seem to find it.

Is there a way in ASP.NET to redirect to a page when a specific error occurs (in my case, when the request is too large). This needs to be just when the error occurs on a specific page, and not just on any page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: catch the exception and then execute a redirect?

Answer (score 1):

As ADyson says in the comments, perhaps a `try - catch` block could be used for this situation.

```
try
{
    // put the code that you want to try here
}
catch(Exception specificException)
{
    return RedirectToAction(actionName, controllerName, routeValues);
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! there is as follows:

**In the `Global.asax` file:**

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();

     HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;

     if (httpException != null)
     {
         if (httpException.GetHttpCode() == 404)
         {
              Server.ClearError();
              Response.Redirect("~/Home/PageNotFound");
              return;
         }
     }

     //Ignore from here if don't want to store the error in database

     HttpContextBase context = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
     RouteData routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(context);

     string controllerName = null;
     string actionName = null;
     if (routeData != null)
     {
         controllerName = routeData.GetRequiredString("controller");
         actionName = routeData.GetRequiredString("action");
     }


     ExceptionModel exceptionModel = new ExceptionModel()
     {
         ControllerName = controllerName ?? "Not in controller",
         ActionOrMethodName = actionName ?? "Not in Action",
         ExceptionMessage = exception.Message,
         InnerExceptionMessage = exception.InnerException != null ? exception.InnerException.Message : "No Inner exception",
         ExceptionTime = DateTime.Now
     };

     using (YourDbContext dbContext = new YourDbContext())
     {
         dbContext.Exceptions.Add(exceptionModel);
         dbContext.SaveChanges();
     }

    // Ignore till here if you don't want to store the error on database

    // clear error on server
    Server.ClearError();
    Response.Redirect("~/Home/Error");
}
```

**Then in the controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult PageNotFound()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Here is everything you need to handle error in ASP.NET MVC Application.You can also customize according to your personal preference.**